# Total energy of the Universe

Tags: general-relativity

In the famous MTW book it is written that

[For a closed universe the total mass-energy and angular momentum is undefined and undefinable]

But there are a lot of claims that the total mass-energy of a closed universe is zero the reason when you vary the action with respect to the the metric tensor the Lagrangian denisty must vanish can anyone explain mathematically what is meant by "when you vary the whole action with respect to the metric tensor the Lagrangian denisty must vanish"

Comment: Are you asking what the variation with respect to the metric means, or why it would be zero?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with studying punctuation before physics.

Comment: Yes , why it would be zero

Comment: Safesphere , i will 